# Can MERGE also DELETE? Example only shows INSERT / UPDATE

Tags: database, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I was reading the MSDN site here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

and I'm a little confused about one thing.

The example from the site (copied at the bottom) uses the line `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`.  My question is, can I use that to do inserts, updates, and deletes all in the same merge?  For example:

```
--Lazy syntax, but I think you get the idea.
MERGE x AS TARGET USING (ID, [More Fields...]) AS SOURCE
WHEN MATCHED
    update
WHEN NOT MATCHED IN TARGET
    insert
WHEN NOT MATCHED IN SOURCE
    delete
```

**MSDN EXAMPLE:**

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
-- Create a temporary table variable to hold the output actions.
DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE(Change VARCHAR(20));

MERGE INTO Sales.SalesReason AS Target
USING (VALUES ('Recommendation','Other'), ('Review', 'Marketing'), 
              ('Internet', 'Promotion'))
       AS Source (NewName, NewReasonType)
ON Target.Name = Source.NewName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET ReasonType = Source.NewReasonType
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Name, ReasonType) VALUES (NewName, NewReasonType)
OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;

-- Query the results of the table variable.
SELECT Change, COUNT(*) AS CountPerChange
FROM @SummaryOfChanges
GROUP BY Change;
```

Comment: At that point you might as well just replace the table?

Comment: Yes you can. @BoeroBoy - Replacing the table may well be overkill. e.g. synchronising two tables where 99% of the rows do match.

Comment: Maybe some better examples here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: @BoeroBoy Martin's right.  The source table is in a staging database which gets replaced daily from a new feed, and we can't take down the production database during the swap as customers use it.  So I'm just looking for the fastest way to make prod match staging without stopping customers from using it while it happens.

Comment: Yes the merge statement supports that. Search the help topic you linked to for "delete".

Comment: You may want to consider replication or log shipping if it's an option.

Comment: @BoeroBoy log shipping is even more intrusive, since you have to kick all users out to restore any log...

Comment: On a 2ndary server (warehouse/failover/archive) that wouldn't be such an issue.  Sounds like that's the purpose here anyway.

Comment: @BoeroBoy but did you notice the requirement added in a comment? The one about not being able to take down the database during the swap because customers are actively using it? You can't accomplish that with log shipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing a wholesale swap of the table, then one way would be to create two additional schemas:

```
CREATE SCHEMA shadow AUTHORIZATION dbo;
CREATE SCHEMA cache  AUTHORIZATION dbo;
```

Now create a copy of your table in the `cache` schema:

```
CREATE TABLE cache.SalesReason(Name ...);
```

Now when you are doing your switch operation:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE cache.SalesReason;
INSERT cache.SalesReason(Name ...) SELECT ... FROM source;

-- this is a metadata operation so extremely fast - it will wait
-- for existing locks to be released, but won't block new locks
-- for very long at all:

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  ALTER SCHEMA shadow TRANSFER Sales.SalesReason;
  ALTER SCHEMA Sales TRANSFER  cache.SalesReason;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

ALTER SCHEMA cache TRANSFER shadow.SalesReason;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache.SalesReason; 
-- truncate is optional - I usually kept the data around for debugging
```

This won't work if you have foreign keys and other dependencies, and of course it completely invalidates statistics etc. and this, in turn, can affect plans, but if the most important thing is getting accurate data in front of your users with minimal interruption, this can be an approach to consider.

Comment: +1, very cool :) I'll probably accept this later.  It's like a C swap function for containers, haha.

Comment: What about switching partitions? That works non non-partitioned tables, too.

Comment: @usr possibly, I haven't really explored that. I'm usually only prepared to speak authoritatively on techniques I have used and hence I know they work. :-)